# Extracting values from Rails collection using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update the contents of a div based on the value selected in a dropdown. The contents of the div come from a Rails collection (specifically ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy). I imagine I should be able to do this without re-querying the database but of course I may be wrong.

Controller

```
def detail
  @workouts = @user.workouts
  @effort = Effort.new
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@effort) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :exercise_id, Exercise.all, :id, :name, {id: 'exercise_select'} %>
<% end %>

<div>
  <% @workouts.each do |wo| %>
  <%= wo.exercise.name %> - <% wo.exercise.weight %> - <%= wo.exercise.sets %><br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm omitting some code so hopefully this still makes sense. What I want to do is just disply one exercise at a time in the div, and I want the exercise displayed to be determined by the exercise selected in the dropdown. I've written the following bit of jQuery a bunch of times

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

});
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed even though I have the exercise_id through the select box.
I'd appreciate it if somebody could give me a steer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty simple if you wrap each workout in it's own element with a unique ID, like "exercise_#{wo.exercise.id}".  You could also give them all a class like "exercise".  In your on change function, then, you could do something like:

```
$('#exercise_select').on('change', function() {
    // determine the id of the selected option
    $('.exercise').hide();
    $('#exercise_'+exerciseID).show();
});
```